# What is the correct formula for coefficient of variation for a binomial distribution?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

```
# Create a binomial random variable with 100 observations and a probability of success of 0.7
binom.data<-rbinom(100, 1, 0.7)

# Calculate the coefficiente of variation (CV(%)) of the binomial random variable
cv.binom.1<-sd(binom.data)/mean(binom.data)*100
cv.binom.1
#[1] 64.23212
```

Ok!! But, I find in some literature that the CV of a binomial random variable is:
The mean of the binomial distribution with parameters n and p is np and the standard deviation is sqrt(np(1-p)). Therefore, the CV is sqrt((1-p)/np):

```
cv.binom.2 <-sqrt((1-0.7)/(100*0.7))*100
cv.binom.2 
#[1] 6.546537
```

I have an expressive difference between the two results. What is the correct way to calculate the CV of a binomial random variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your theoretical formula is correct! So, why do the simulated results so grossly disagree with theoretical results?

You simulated 100 realizations from a binomial distributions with $n = 1, p=0.7$, but calculated the CV for a binomial with $n=100, p =0.7$. This is a quite common trap to run into: the `n` in `rbinom(n, size, p)` stands for the number of simulated values, and `size` is the parameter $n$ of the binomial. Try with `binom.data<-rbinom(10000, 100, 0.7)` instead, for example.
Edit: you can change the number of simulated values, here I chose 10000 to get lower variation, that is, a higher chance to have a simulated result close to the theoretical value.

Comment: Why `N = 10000` in the code?

Comment: Just to make the simulation more precise. You can also use 100, or 999, or whatever you like. Try several times with the same number `n` of simulated values, and you will see how the much the results vary as a consequence of how many simulations you run